# Tagged items not appearing correctly in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

I'm running OS X 10.9.5. Recently, I used Handbrake 0.9.9 x86_64 (2013051800) to convert some WMVs to MP4s. There are roughly 150 videos, and I have attempted to tag them all. When in their respective folders, they look fairly normal, as this example demonstrates:

[image: normal file]

However, when I click on 'Blue' in the Finder sidebar, I see this for each video:

[image: abnormal file]

I am not having the same problem with any other files tagged with the same tag, and that includes seventeen other videos which I converted from AVIs to MP4s using the same Handbrake preset (there *may* have been a difference in the settings for picture size, but I don't think there was). This may mean it's completely unconnected to Handbrake, but it seems unlikely.

I tried running `ls -l` on the directory containing the affected videos and the directory containing the seventeen unaffected videos and they're all `-rw-r--r--@`. Both sets of files have the extended attribute `com.apple.metadata:_kMDIItemUserTags`.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reindexing my drive with `sudo mdutil -E /path/to/volume` the files showed in the tag list correctly, so it was clearly an issue with the Spotlight index; hopefully this helps someone else in the future.