# Tagged Folder Not Appearing in Tags List OS X Yosemite

Tags: finder-tag

I have tagged a folder about a dozen folders down the hierarchy but the folder does not appear in the tagged folders in the finder after tagging it with right click and tag color selection.

How can I create a link to a folder using tags that works?

Comment: I just notice the same issue in Mavericks.  Here is a discussion thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5470591?start=15&tstart=0 though the solutions proposed there didn't work for me.

Comment: By the way, see also this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/150401/111158 (I didn't try that solution yet)